# Creating new CSS element everytime database updates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I have created a function using jQuery Ajax which create a new CSS element whenever I update the database using a form.

Is it ok?  If not, hat can be the best method to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#statusupdater').submit(function(e) {
        updatestatus();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function updatestatus()
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "statusupdate.php",
    data: $('#statusupdater').serialize(),
    dataType: "dataString"          
});
$('#statuscontainer').prepend( $('<div id="stat">').load('statusupdate.php'));
$("#statusupdater")[0].reset();
    $('.statuspop').fadeOut(300);
            $('#opacify').hide();
}
```

**statusupdate.php**

```
<?php include "dbcon.php"; 

 $status=$_POST['status'];
 $photo=$_POST['photoupload'];

 if ($status || $photo)
 {
    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s');
    $statusinsert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO status (st_id,statu,date_created,userid) VALUES ('','$status','$date','$id')" );
 }

 $selectstatus = mysqli_query($con,"select * from status where userid = '".$id."' order by st_id desc limit 1");
 $getstatus=mysqli_fetch_array($selectstatus);
 ?>

    <div class="statbar"><?php echo $getstatus["userid"];?></div>
    <div class="stattxt"><?php echo $getstatus["statu"];?></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the return datatype to html and update the DOM in the success callback:

```
function updatestatus()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "statusupdate.php",
        data: $('#statusupdater').serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data, status, xhrObj){
            $('#statuscontainer').prepend($('<div id="stat">').html(data));
            $("#statusupdater")[0].reset();
            $('.statuspop').fadeOut(300);
            $('#opacify').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

You could also update the DOM using the `error` and `statusCode` callbacks if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't much here and Ben got the big one. In addition to using the success callback, you could pass the form into your `updatestatus()` function. This will allow you to reuse this code, if necessary, and forces you to use a referenced pointer to the jQuery object rather than forcing jQuery to rebuild it every time you need to do something with it. Additionally, if you use the form's `action` and `method` attributes you wont have to worry about changing the `url` and `type` indices on multiple pages.

```
updatestatus( $( this ) );

function updatestatus( $form ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr( 'method' ),
        url: $form.attr( 'action' ),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function( data ){
            $('#statuscontainer').prepend($('<div id="stat">').html(data));
            $form[0].reset();
            $('.statuspop').fadeOut(300);
            $('#opacify').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Finally, you should really sanitize user input instead of using it directly.

```
$status = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'status', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
```

The only other thing I've really noticed is some minor inconsistencies in styling.